# How to set position for InputDriver.emit() event?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, touch-event, touchscreen, android-things

I have Android Things 1.0 Raspberry Pi 3 and `800x480` (`width / height`) touch pad and need to track user touches on it for `Activity` layout controls. I'm got touch `x` and `y` coordinates from touch pad and try to generate Android touch event with that code:

```
private InputDriver mInputDriver;
private InputDriverEvent mInputDriverEvent = new InputDriverEvent();

...
int x = getTouchX();     // returns x within [0, 800]
int y = getTouchY();     // returns y within [0, 480]
mInputDriverEvent.clear();
mInputDriverEvent.setPosition(MotionEvent.AXIS_X, x);
mInputDriverEvent.setPosition(MotionEvent.AXIS_Y, y);
mInputDriverEvent.setContact(true);

mInputDriver.emit(mInputDriverEvent);
...
```

where `mInputDriver` initialized that way:

```
mInputDriver = new InputDriver.Builder()
    .setName("TouchPad")
    .setVendorId(0)
    .setProductId(0)
    .setAxisConfiguration(MotionEvent.AXIS_X, 0, 800, 0 ,0)
    .setAxisConfiguration(MotionEvent.AXIS_Y, 0, 480, 0 ,0)
    .build();
UserDriverManager.getInstance().registerInputDriver(mInputDriver);
```

event was generated for every touch, but pointer (cursor) always is in the screen center:

[image: Touch point and pointer (cursor) position]

How to move pointer (cursor) to `(x,y)` position on screen?

Comment: what if you switch the x and y? and then what if you take into account the height of the toolbar?

Comment: @Blundell 1) nothing changed; 2) pointer always at the center of screen.

Comment: we'd need to see more code to recreate the problem as a simple example. From here https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/input I can't tell if you require the permission, if you use a service etc

Comment: @Blundell Permission already granted. The code is like in a question - there nothing more. Actually I'm almost done a workaround: seems coordinate system for InputDriver.emit() event is relative. It's necessary to emit two events: first for move to current position (relative `[0,0]` coords) and than - second event with `[dx,dy]` coords - relative to current. But it's weird.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko you [miss-reviewed here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21720164). Have a look at [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1033581), clarifying that link-only answers should be deleted.